# help needed to find the 5th term on the number series

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

Can someone help me calculate the 5th term of these two series of numbers? They are somewhat difficult because they have no common difference or ration, which means they are neither arithmetic nor geometric.
7,1,2,3,___ the 5th term seems to be 5, but I don't know how to get it.
6,7,7,12___ The 5th term is 7, also I don't know how to get it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It is obviously 42, as Douglas Adams brilliantly observed in "The Hichhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" as the answer to the ultimate question.

Seriously, *any* sequence (and thus any following values) are possible. Without any further information on the sequence, my guess is as good as any other.

Answer (score 1):

The online encyclopedia of integer sequences ([oeis.org](https://oeis.org)) is a great resource. Unfortunately, your cases are weird.

Searches for [$7,1,2,3$](https://oeis.org/search?q=7%2C1%2C2%2C3&sort=&language=english&go=Search) and [$6,7,7,12$](https://oeis.org/search?q=6%2C7%2C7%2C12&sort=&language=english&go=Search) return hits appearing unsatisfyingly late in their respective sequences. Even if you knew the answer ahead of time, they wouldn't fit any well known sequences.

For better results, we can loosen our affinity for the question's accuracy: For example, the Fibonacci sequence starts $1,1,2,3,5$. Pi times zeta($2$) equals $\frac{\pi^3}{6} = 5.1\textbf{677127}\dots$.

Comment: A273432  seems to be the answer, but I can not understand the solution.

Comment: @Ema [this one?](https://oeis.org/A273432) the answer to which sequence?

Comment: This sequence 7,1,2,3,4  https://oeis.org/search?q=7%2c1%2c2%2c3%2c5&start=10

Comment: That link is for $7,1,2,3,5$ and $A273432$ doesnt appear in the results.

Comment: do you think you can explain how they got 5 as the 5th term? thanks in advance

Comment: I can’t. Its unclear who you mean by they. Whatever sequence you’re looking at is too weird to be obvious.